# foundation.modal Angular Module with own state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

We are using the [Foundation Angular Modules](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/angular-modules) foundation.modal / ModalFactory to display a set of user input views. Each view needs to have data passed into it. I've so far brought in some basic data but we now need to make API calls for each individual modal, and in some cases when the modal first loads. This is difficult to achieve when everything is all in one controller / state.

Currently it is looping through all the data and creating the modal config for each item all in the listing state.

E.g.

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myModuleController', [
    '$scope',
    'things',
    'ModalFactory',


    function(scope, things, ModalFactory) {
       scope.things = things;

        // General pluralised when necessary questions label
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.things.length; i++) {

            // attach config and other parts for modal
            if (scope.things[i].items.length > 0) {
                var config = {
                    // unique id for modal div
                    id: scope.things[i]._id,
                    templateUrl: module.path + '/views/modal.html',
                    contentScope: {
                        item: scope.things[i].items[0],
                        thing: scope.things[i],
                        // this should really be its own state so we can use 'resolve'
                        gotFromApi: function() { return GetFromApi(); } 
                    }
                  },
                    animationIn: 'slideInFromTop'
                };
            }
        }
    }
]};
```

What we want is for each modal to have its own state, so we can use a separate Angular module, equivalent to a 'show/edit item' view, and use the `resolve` to grab data from our API when necessary.

Is there a way to achieve this with the Foundation Modal Directive?

We've found an example of modals in Angular using states here: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-stateful-modals-angularjs-angular-ui-router/

Wondering if anyone knows a way of doing something similar with Foundation.